# mysqli_stmt_execute doesn't update random rows when using specific number in query?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

This is the strangest thing - I have dynamically generated form that, when processed, updates a database table with prices. All seems to work correctly except when I use a specific price?

And this only happens to random rows:

Eg: If I change the price to 67.48 - the rows in question are updated perfectly.

However if I use the price 67.49 then the rows are not updated?

I'm completely stumped. Here is my update code.

```
// Define the queries:
    $q1 = 'UPDATE variations SET retail_price= ? WHERE id=?';

    // Prepare the statements:
    $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q1);

    // Bind the variables:
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, 'ii', $price, $id);

    // Count the number of affected rows:
    $affected = 0;

    // Loop through each submitted value:
    foreach ($_POST['add'] as $sku => $price) {

        //parse the price remove decimals
            $price = $price*100; 

        // Validate the added quantity:
        if (filter_var($price, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1))) {

            // Parse the SKU:
            $id = parse_sku($sku);


                // Execute the query:
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);

                // Add to the affected rows:
                $affected += mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt1);             


        } // End of IF.

    } // End of FOREACH.
```

Comment: What does `parse_sku()` do?

Comment: Notice that even after multiplying by 100, the datatype is still a float.  Is that perhaps a part of the issue?  https://3v4l.org/iKqSQ  What happens if you explicitly cast the "product" (result of multiplication) as an integer?  `$price = (int)($price * 100);`

Comment: How do you know the price is not updated? For a question like this you have to provide a complete reproducible example: a database dump with the existing value, an update query, followed by a select query that demonstrates that value didn't change. If you cannot probide such an example, then your problem is something else

Comment: @You Off-topic: Not Reproducible?

Answer (score -1):

You are insterted double value in the database (for the price), but you are telling to PHP to treat the value as integer (using the `i`).
You need to use `d` for double.

Your code to bind the params will be:

```
// Bind the variables:
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, 'di', $price, $id);
```

Comment: They do `$price = $price*100; ` before inserting the value.